# Special character in SQLPLUS broken vertical bar

Tags: oracle, solaris, sqlplus

I have a text column that some rows include a broken vertical bar character '¦' .  Using SQLDeveloper (on Win10 desktop), I can select it, insert it, etc.  But when I try the same query using SQLPlus (on Solaris 10 server), it does not match.  I have tried a variety of copy/paste, typing, scp from Windows, etc. but all are failing.

Here is the query that works in SQLDeveloper:

```
select * from foo.baz where baq like '%¦%';
```

Any helpful suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a charset issue.. Have you tried setting NLS_LANG to UTF8 before starting SQL*Plus? e.g. `export NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8`

Comment: You could try like this:
select * from foo.baz where baq like  '%'||'¦'||%'

Comment: The export NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8 worked.  Thanks kfinity .  The '%'||'¦'||'%'  did not work - no rows returned.